# ASP.Net - referenced assembly - current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I have an ASP.Net project that references an assembly that does a lot of database work and so there are a lot of connection strings in the assembly's app.config file. All of the connection strings are application scoped not user-scoped. I have tried putting the connection strings the the ASP.Net web.config but still keep getting the following exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings.' The code clearly shows that the ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute is in place.

```
    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass")]
    public string AConnectionString {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["AConnectionString"]));
        }
    }
```